# How do I assign a counter attribute inside a class?

Tags: python, class, attributes, subclass

This is my first time working with classes. I'm trying to understand how I can assign a counter as an attribute of both parent and sub classes. I don't understand how I can count the elements of an object. I understand how to count the # of objects/instances of that specific class.

**This is how I understand counting/iterating through elements with a for loop**

```
# Parent Class
class Color:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Color'
        
# Inherent Classes
class Green(Color):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Green'
        
class Red(Color):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Red'

# Random Generator:
from random import choice
colorL = [choice(['Red', 'Green']) for randomI in range(20)]

cRed = cGreen = 0
for color in colorL:
 if color == 'Green':
   cGreen=cGreen+1
 else:
   cRed=cRed+1

# Print statements of random list, max count & specific count of inherent classes   
print(colorL)
print("Total # of colors:", len(colorL))
print("# of Greens:", cGreen)
print("# of Reds:", cRed)
```

**This is my attempt to define count inside a class but the parent shape returns:**

*Total # of colors: <built-in method count of list object at 0x7fd13f4acf08>*

**and the sub classes return an AttributeError:**

*AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'count'*

```
# Parent Class
class Color:
    def __init__(self, name, count):
        count = 0
        self.name = 'Color'
        self.count += 1
        
# Inherent Classes
class Green(Color):
    def __init__(self, name, count):
        count = 0
        self.name = 'Green'
        self.count += 1
        
class Red(Color):
    def __init__(self, name, count):
        count = 0
        self.name = 'Red'
        self.count += 1

# Random Generator:
from random import choice
colorL = [choice(['Red', 'Green']) for randomI in range(20)]

for color in colorL:
    if color == 'Green':
        GreenC = Green.count
    else:
        RedC = Red.count

# Print statements of random list, max count & specific count of inherent classes   
print(colorL)
print("Total # of colors:", colorL.count)
print("# of Greens:", GreenC.count)
print("# of Reds:", RedC.count)
```

Comment: Your code is confusing. In neither snippet do you make any instances of the classes you declare.

Comment: Please update your question with your actual code. If I attempt to run your second snippet I don't get the errors that you claim to see.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that you were actually after:

```py
# Base Class
class Color:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        Color.count += 1
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

# Derived Classes
class Green(Color):
    count = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Green')
        Green.count += 1
        
class Red(Color):
    count = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Red')
        Red.count += 1

# Random Generator:
from random import choice
colorL = [choice([Red, Green])() for _ in range(20)]

# Print statements of random list, max count & specific count of derived classes
print(colorL)
print("Total # of colors:", Color.count)
print("# of Greens:", Green.count)
print("# of Reds:", Red.count)
```

This code creates instances of the declared classes and makes them keep a separate count of how many were created without having to do a count ourselves.